# GPS module NEO M8M not responding with Atmega 328P

Tags: arduino-uno, gps

I designed PCb for relay Switching using gps signal for that i am using atmaga 328P-AU and Neo 6M but after connecting gps module its not showing long, lat. i also checked power supply in module pin it shows 4.96V and RX, TX connection are also properly soldered.

i tested simple code to see the uart data in module and it should be something regardless of satelite connection but it shows nothing.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(4, 5); //(RX, TX) check correct pin assignments.

void setup() {

mySerial.begin(9600);

Serial.begin(9600);

Serial.println("GPS start");

}

void loop() {

while (mySerial.available()) {

Serial.write(
mySerial.read());

}

}
```

in serial monitor it only shows "GPS start" when i press reset button

Schematic

[image]

my pcb layout

[image]

Actual PCB
[image]

So far i have tried this things but didnt get any result.

1.swapping RX,TX pins.

2.changing GPS module.

3.kept gps module in balcony for more than 4 hours.

4.connection checked more than 10 times.

Comment: is the GPS module oriented correctly in the plug?

Comment: also posted at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/667300/gps-module-neo-m8m-not-responding-with-atmega-328p

Comment: yes it is oriented correctly